# ubuntu linux - visible bell or screen flash

Tags: linux

I'm using Ubuntu Linux with Gnome.  Is it possible to create a visible bell, or a screen flash?  I often run programs in terminal that download files or some other process that takes a half hour or so and when they are done, I would like to be notified visually.  There is a beep command in the terminal, is there something like this that operates visually in Gnome?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92864/sound-notification-in-terminal) Ask Ubuntu question.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, this is not possible in gnome-terminal (although individual programs, e. g. GNU screen, may allow you to use some kind of visual notification for the terminal bell).

If you use Konsole, though (the default KDE terminal program), you can configure [many actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAmpF.png) associated with the bell through Settings > Configure Notifications.